# Run .cu files in colab with octave

Tags: matlab, octave, google-colaboratory

I have to use code that was written in matlab and CUDA ([here](https://www.math.snu.ac.kr/%7Eernestryu/code/OMT/OMT_code.zip)). Unfortunately, my laptop does not have the hardware to run it. So I (naively) thought about using google colab and octave. Does that make sense in the first place?
I want to run VOMT_tester.m, which uses the command

```
mexcuda -g vomt_mex.cu
```

in the first line. This command does not exist in octave. As far as I know, I have to use `!mkoctfile`, but it does not accept the `.cu`-extension. I read about using trying this

```
!nvcc  /content/omt_code/vomt_mex.cu
```

This is the output:

> /content/omt_code/vomt_mex.cu:5:10: fatal error: mex.h: No such file or directory
> #include "mex.h"
> ^~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.

I dont have this header. And I guess that it is not possible to install this on a google drive. Is there anything, I can do here?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you can get the matlab->octave translation done, there is no support in octave for the type of integration that matlab provides for CUDA.  So you would have to do a significant amount of rewriting of the code.  There isn't a sequence of commands that will do it for you.

Comment: thanks! Could it work out in python?

Comment: octave _does_ provide a mex.h header, which, in theory should be compatible. If you have the octave sources it is in `libinterp/corefcn/mex.h`. _IF_ that is the only thing missing, and _IF_ the code is generic enough to not use matlab-specialised features, then yes, you should be able to compile with nvcc, and then use the generated object with mkoctfile -mex to generate an octave-compatible mexfile.